# Hibernate not creating index in beta

Tags: mysql, hibernate, amazon-aurora

I am using hibernate to create and manage tables. I have added a unique index constraint on a pair of column but when the table gets created the index is missing in beta. The same code when it runs in prod is creating the index and everything is working fine in prod.

Why is the index not created in beta and how can i create it?

When i try to manually add the index then i get `Error Code: 1071. Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`. 
The columns on which i have to apply the constraints are both `varchar(255)`.

PS: I am using Amazon's Aurora for my SQL db.